# Where to put the link in this code for the subscribe button?

Tags: html, forms, button, hyperlink

I found this code template that I want to use for a newsletter sign up form. I can't figure out where to put the link in this code for the subscribe button. I don't want to have to create a new button. I have tried using an action code as well as href.

```html
 <div class="span4"> 
    <div class="p30"> 
      
        <h3>Newsletter</h3> 
      <form class="soundest-subscribe" style="width: 100%;">
              <input type="text" class="soundest-subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter your email address" style="width: 100%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #a0a0a0; font-size: 14px; font-family: Times New Roman, ; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; outline-width: 0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" /> 
    
    <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" style="width : 100%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: ;  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; padding: 8px; margin-top: 5px; background-color: #a2a2a2; border-width: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; outline-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;"  />
        </form> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You can set it by giving `action` attribute value to `form` element.
`<form class="soundest-subscribe" style="width: 100%; action="subscribe.php"">`. 
Inorder to perform the logic you at least need a serverside code to handle the logic.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="span4"> 
  <div class="p30"> 

    <h3>Newsletter</h3> 
    <form class="soundest-subscribe" style="width: 100%;">
      <input type="text" class="soundest-subscribe-input" placeholder="Enter your email address" style="width: 100%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #a0a0a0; font-size: 14px; font-family: Times New Roman, ; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; outline-width: 0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" /> 

      <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" style="width : 100%; height: 34px; display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 14px; font-weight: ;  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; padding: 8px; margin-top: 5px; background-color: #a2a2a2; border-width: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; outline-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;"  />
    </form> 
  </div>
```

Please observe action in your form and clicking on the button user will be navigated to www.google.com. You can replace the url mentioned in form action with your own.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me!